# Modifying code within a protected method

Tags: java, protected

I was wondering if it was possible to override a protected method that is in a 3rd Party jar file. I am guessing I can invoke the method using reflection, but how would I completely overwrite it?

The method is

```
protected void a(World world, int i, int j, int k, ItemStack itemstack) {
    if (!world.isStatic && world.getGameRules().getBoolean("doTileDrops")) {
        float f = 0.7F;
        double d0 = (double) (world.random.nextFloat() * f) + (double) (1.0F - f) * 0.5D;
        double d1 = (double) (world.random.nextFloat() * f) + (double) (1.0F - f) * 0.5D;
        double d2 = (double) (world.random.nextFloat() * f) + (double) (1.0F - f) * 0.5D;
        EntityItem entityitem = new EntityItem(world, (double) i + d0, (double) j + d1, (double) k + d2, itemstack);
        entityitem.pickupDelay = 10;
        world.addEntity(entityitem);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can `override` protected method outside your own package if you inherit from the class that it belongs to.

Comment: I didn't get your question. If it is a protected method, you can override it by extending the class. Check [Java Access Modifiiers](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_access_modifiers.htm)

Comment: I know I can override it, but I do not know how to have other plugins use the overridden method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the point of `protected` methods is that they can be overridden by subclass implementations in different packages/modules (the default access mode allows to do that only from the same package).

It is then up to the subclass to decide if it wants to call back into the super method or not.

So you could have

```
class MyVersion extends TheClass {

     @Override
     protected void a(World world, int i, int j, int k, ItemStack itemstack) {
         // do something else
     }

}
```

Of course, the more interesting question is how to make the rest of the application use your new version instead of the original. If it is your code that drives instantiation of this object, then that is no problem. Otherwise, you may have to find some configuration setting or change some more code.

Comment: should be 'same' package.

Comment: Yea, I figured that would work, but I have no idea how to force everything else attached to use my version, which is why I was kinda hoping to override it while the server itself is starting up so when other plugins access the method, it would then use the new one.

Comment: You probably need to replace the jar file with a patched version. Hard to tell without more details.

Comment: That is a route I thought of but something I would really like to avoid if possible. Is there really no other way? Is it possible to see when the original method is run, intercept it, cancel it, and run the new one instead?